# PowerShell: Get-ChildItem list .jpg file name that include certain "tags" keywords in metadata | export to CSV

Tags: image, powershell, jpeg, photo, get-childitem

I have a directory of many image (.jpg) files and I would like to export the file names to .csv or .txt

However, I only want to list files that contain certain "Tags" (metadata) in their Description (e.g. "dog"). How can specify this and then export the list to a .csv file?

I was able to get ALL the files with .jpg extensions with the following command:

`Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Out-File -FilePath .\filenames.txt`

However, this does not filter files that contain the tag "dogs" in the metadata.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "*dog*.jpg"`? Have a look at the *built-in* help for `Get-ChildItem` by running, `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full` in your powershell window

Comment: PoSh does not have direct access to the file metadata on windows. you will need to look into getting that yourself. take a look at >>> Use PowerShell to Find Metadata from Photograph Files | Scripting Blog — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/